# Can a childVC of XLPagerStrip have a navigation item?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, xlpagertabstrip

I'm using XLPagerTabStrip, I'm trying to have navigation controller in my child so I can use BTNavigationDropdownMenu and embed it inside my navigation item, so far I have failed to achieve the navigation bar visible in my child even though the VC has NC embed in it